# "TypeError.parent.context.car.getBrands is not a function": s

Tags: http, typescript, angular

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getCars(){
        return this.http.get...       
    }

    getById(id: string) {
        return this.http.get...       
    }    
}
```

Car class:

```
export class Car {

    private brands: Array<Brand>;

    constructor(public id: string, public name: string) {
        this.brands = new Array<Brand>();
    }

    public getBrands(): Array<Brand> {
        return this.brands;
    }
    //some other methods.
}
```

Then I have a Brand class (object) with it's own attributes and methods and so on and and so on...

car.list.component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'car-list',
    template: `
    //some more code here
    <table>
        <tr *ngFor="let car of cars" >
        <td>{{car.name}}</td>
        <td><button (click)="goToDetail(car)">Detail</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  `,
})


export class ListComponent implements OnActivate {
    id: string
    name: string;
    cars: Array<Car>

    constructor(public _service: Service, public _router: Router) {   }

    routerOnActivate(): void {
        this._service.getCars()
            .subscribe(cars => this.cars = cars);
    }
 }
```

And then the problem, the car.detail.component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'car-detail',
    template: `  
    <h1>Car: {{car?.name}}</h1>
    <hr>
    <div *ngFor="let brand of car?.getBrands(); let i=index">  
        <h2>Brand {{i+1}}</h2>
    </div>   

`,
})

export class DetailComponent implements OnActivate {

    @Input() car: Car;

    constructor(public _service: Service, public _router: Router) {    }

    routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment): void {
        let id = curr.getParam('id');
        this._service.getById(id)
            .subscribe(car => {
                this.car = car;
            });
    }
    //some other methods
}
```

When calling `car.getBrands()` it gives error: `TypeError: self.parent.context.car?.getBrands is not a function`

Comment: Where do you use `self.parent.context.car.getBrands`? The code in your question doesn't show any. What browser are you using? Can you try force-reload (Ctrl+F5 or Ctrl+r in Chrome)

Comment: can't force-reload either in chrome or firefox. I think I have all code provided that is needed?? The service that handles the car http (retrieval, adding and so on) Then the Car object that contains Array of Brand objects. The detail component is the problem, that I when I try to retrieve the brands of the specific car chosen. The call is in the car-detail template.

Comment: I'd assume the code mentioned in the error message is the problem ;-) and that is not included in your question. The browser doesn't introduce variables like `self`, therefore it has to be from your code.

Comment: Well this is ALL the code that exists for the the first part, so I haven't even gotten further than this after connecting the db to my code. I have some more code in the template in the detail component , but I have actually removed it yesterday (just in case), so I know exactly where the problem is and that there is no code after this that can mess it up. So my code works up to this point where I call car.getBrands. So this is actually all the code I use at the time for my app. So I don't know....?

Comment: I guess you **had** such code in your application because it doen't look like code coming from somewhere else. In this case it's an issue with your system. Try clearing the cache in the browser and killing the HTTP server you're using and then try again.

Comment: Did it, still no luck. I even deleted the two "Cars" I had in my DB and added some new cars in my browser as that works well, as well as removing and listing them. AND checked the backend that everything has the right attributes and names, and that the correct data is indeed coming in from the backend.... like I've done a thousand times. Man I love coding, but it drives me nuts :D I thought that after a good nights sleep I'd wake up with some brilliant ideas on how to fix this, all day gone and no ideas :D

Comment: What IDE are you using? Try searching the full project for `self.parent`. I don't see how to provider further help. I'm sure the problem isn't caused by the code you posted.

Comment: Visual Studio Code for front Eclipse for back. I'll check the whole project. Thanks for your help regardless :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the likely problem is located here:

```
 this._service.getById(id)
    .subscribe(car => {
      this.car = car; // you just init object like { id: '1', name: 'name'}
    });
```

[image]

Probably your service looks like this:

```
getById(id: string) {
   return this.http.get('app/car.json')
     .map(data => data.json());     
}
```

Try to get `Car` model from service like this:

```
getById(id: string) {
   return this.http.get('app/car.json')
     .map(data => data.json())
     .map(car => new Car(car.id, car.name));  <== add this line   
}
```

This way `car` will be instance of `Car` class and will have appropriate methods like `getBrands`, `addBrand`...
[image]

Hope it helps!