# Angular can't find the function when calling it via a DOM element

Tags: angular

I've got a strange bug which makes no sense to me at all.

```
TypeError: self.parent.context.toggleChecked is not a function
```

I get this error whenever I click on an item which I've bound the listener to.. I'm using the normal `addEventListener` right now instead of `Renderer` because I've got another component which I haven't rewritten yet and that works, while this example doesn't (doesn't work with `Renderer` either).

Why can't it find the `toggleChecked` function when it's clearly there? It works if I just call it without using an event listener.

What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

```
export class FormCheckboxMultipleComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @Input() model: Array<any>;
  @Output('modelChange') onModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() callback: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private _globals: GlobalVariablesService, private _renderer: Renderer, private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.ns = _globals.ns;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model = this.model || [];
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    let list = this._elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('my-mom')[0];
    let options = list.getElementsByTagName('li');

    for (let option of options) {

      option.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        this.toggleChecked(e);
      });
    }
  }

  toggleChecked(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you create the list and `li` elements? Here is a similar error message mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37642675/typeerrorelf-parent-context-car-getbrands-is-not-a-function-s but it seems to be caused by something different.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I just transclude it like so: `<form-checkbox-multiple><li></li></form-checkbox-multiple>`

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: why not use ng-click?

Comment: @YOU Because it won't know what the component function is if using transclusion.

Comment: try adding .bind(this) on eventListener function?

Comment: @YOU That's what I'm doing, but in a different way.

Comment: or is there a chance that let option create different scope? anyway try adding console.log(this) inside eventListener function, to see what is this